# Problems with the variable Webdriver driver when I use PageObjects

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, bdd, cucumber-java

I want to use: Login_Page Login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Login_Page.class); in a unique way in all steps.
When I use it for each step I have no problems, but on the contrary Java shows me the error: " Value driver is always 'null'".

I would also like to replace Thread.sleep (2000); for a better solution.[image]

Here is my Code:

```
package stepdefs;

import Pages.Login_Page;
import cucumber.api.java.pt.Dado;
import cucumber.api.java.pt.Entao;
import cucumber.api.java.pt.Quando;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class StepDefinitions {

      WebDriver driver;
      Login_Page Login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Login_Page.class);

      @Dado("^que que estou na pagina principal do Gmail\\.$")
    public void que_que_estou_na_pagina_principal_do_Gmail () throws Exception
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\browsers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.gmail.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Quando("^forneco as credenciais validas\\.$")
    public void forneco_as_credenciais_validas () throws Exception {
      // Login_Page Login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Login_Page.class);
        Login.setEmail("rbkamontana@gmail.com");
        Login.ClickOnNextButton();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Login.setSenha("automation10");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Login.ClickOnEnterButton();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }

    @Entao("^posso ver que estou logado\\.$")
    public void posso_ver_que_estou_logado () throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb\"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a/span")).click();
        String stringAtual = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb\"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]")).getText();
        String StringEsperada = "Rebeka Montana";
        Assert.assertTrue(stringAtual.contains(StringEsperada));
        //driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Thread.sleep you can use selenium WebDriverWait function by a Locator.

Ref:
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html

```
void waitForElement(By Locator){
    WebDriverWait myWait = new WebDriverWait(myDriver, 20);
    myWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(Locator));
}
```

Try initiating this inside of a constructor instead:

```
 public StepDefinitions(){
 driver = new ChromeDriver();
 Login  = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Login_Page.class);
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work ..  public StepDefinitions(){
 Login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Login_Page.class);
 }

Comment: I want to use: Login_Page Login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Login_Page.class); in a unique way in all steps. When I use it for each step I have no problems, but on the contrary Java shows me the error: " Value driver is always 'null'".

Answer (score 0):

An instance method is initializing the `driver` field at runtime, which explains why things work inside the step definition method. The solution is deceptively simple: create a getter method for the page model:

```
public class StepDefinitions {
    WebDriver driver;
    Login_Page login;

    private Login_Page getLoginPage() {
        if (login == null) {
            login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Login_Page.class);
        }

        return login;
    }

    @Quando("^forneco as credenciais validas\\.$")
    public void forneco_as_credenciais_validas () throws Exception {
        Login_Page login = getLoginPage();

        login.setEmail("rbkamontana@gmail.com");
        login.ClickOnNextButton();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        login.setSenha("automation10");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        login.ClickOnEnterButton();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
```